# iOS - How to hardware accelerate MKV (+ others unsupported) playing

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I saw that a few video players (e.g. AVPlayerHD) are doing hardware-accelerated playing on iOS for unsupported containers like MKV. How do you think they're achieving that?

I'm thinking reading packet with ffmpeg, decoding with Core Video. Does that make sense? I'm trying to achieve the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the HW accelerators for video rendering (decoding) support fixed formats, due to hard wired logic. I don't know of any HW accelerator to be able to transcode from MKV.

Another method of accelerating video playback, would be the usage of OpenCL and make use of the integrated GPU on your device. This method enables HW acceleration of a wider area of applications.

The problem with this approach is that if you are not lucky enough to find a framework that uses OpenCL to do GPU acceleration of transcode / decode, you probably need to do it yourself.

**Added info**

To implement a fully HW accelerated solution you first need to transcode the MKV into H264 & sub, and from there you can use the HW decoder to render the H264 component.

For the HW accelerated transcode operations you could use GPU (via OpenCL) and/or multithreading.

I found https://handbrake.fr/ that might have some OpenCL transcoding features.

Cheers!

Comment: Container formats or video formats? Because most MKVs have H264 video, which is a supported format on iOS. Only the container is not...